# Re-send a Dropbox invitation using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dropbox-api

If you are looking for a way to have a technical support person re-send a Dropbox invitation, without making them an Admin and using the Admin console, the following code will give them that capability.

```
# Prompt for Team Member Management permission 
#$token = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your Dropbox Business API App token (Team Member Management permission): " 
$token = "Bearer LFaDKviemndvsifm72vknmefbLhggLl6XX8p78dknvi3emvecdfUq8O0lQ2UEUE_QX9zh" #replace with your value

 # Prompt for Team Member email to send invitation 
 $EmailInvite = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the email address to re-send the Dropbox invitation" 

 $object = New-Object psobject 

 $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name '.tag' -Value "email"
 $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name email -Value $EmailInvite


try {
 # Make API Call to resend invitation
 $InviteStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.dropbox.com/2/team/members/send_welcome_email -Body (ConvertTo-Json $object) -ContentType application/json -Headers @{ 
                 Authorization = $token } -Method Post 

} catch {
# Caught an error, just display it as the web API sends it back.

#  Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
#  Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription

$result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
$reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
$reader.DiscardBufferedData()
$responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();

$responseBody

}
```

Comment: This seems useful but is not a question. I think this could be salvaged by editing the question to ask how to do this and then providing this code in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the Bearer authorization number with one you generate for this code to work for your Dropbox Business or Enterprise team (see Dropbox.com/developer for more information on this).